# How to get commented section of the html code using requests?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get number of followers of a facebook page i.e. https://web.facebook.com/marlenaband. I am using python `requests` library. When I see the page source in the browser, the text "142 people follow this" appears to be in the commented section of the page. But, I am not seeing it in the response text using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`. Would someone please help me on how to get this? Thanks

Here is the code I am using:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://web.facebook.com/marlenaband'
headers = {
'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 UBrowser/7.0.185.1002 Safari/537.36',
}
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(res.content)
```

Comment: facebook front is mainly a huge js application (as you can tell from your response's content), so you won't get those info with `requests` - you'll need a js-enabled client. Selenium is the de facto standard here.

Comment: I actually got it using `requests`. Thanks

Comment: Yes ??? Then you may want to post your solution (and the process that led you to the solution) for other peoples having the same need.

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it using `requests` by modifying the `headers` to this:

```
headers = {
    'accept-language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
}
```